# Node.JS: Working with multiple Git repositories

Tags: node.js, git, repository, npm

We have a node.js project with a few modules which spans across multiple Git repositories. The modules have dependencies between them.

For example:

`common` module resides in its own repository.
`execution` module resides in a separate repository, and has a (npm) dependency on `common`.

So, the directory structure in `execution` includes (once `npm install` is executed) `common` under `node_modules`.

Our problem is, when developers are working on `execution`, they some times need to modify `common` as well. In order to 'see' their changes, they have one of two options we currently use: Either modify `node_modules/common` (which is ugly, untracked, etc.), or modify the `common` repository, then *push+npm install* their changes (which, while cleaner, is quite cumbersome).

What we're wondering is if there's a better alternative for this work process...

Comment: did you consider having a single git repo (monorepo)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are using them as a dependency using package.json, which allows you to require them with the name and not the path. (*You also have goodies of the version handling with this.*) . I couldnt find any option to remove the step of npm install but I did found something which can remove the step of git push and will make your npm install faster.

**Local dependencies.**
Using local paths as dependencies which can be your some other git repo, you can make changes directly to the git repo of your dependency. This allows you to change the code and test it without pushing. (Although you have to do npm install again in the main module, which will duplicate the working copy of your dependency in your node modules).

Word of caution : You have to take care that you push the final changes made to your dependency code once you have finished working on both, otherwise other developers might go in inconsistent state.

**How to add local dependencies**

```
 "dependencies" : {
       "here" : "file:./test/git/repo/here#0.0.1"
 }
```

Note that this local dependency feature was added to npm in version 2.0. So you might need to update your node if you dont already have npm 2.0+

Comment: Hi Vishwanath, 
Thanks. I'm going to try this (specifically, we're going to give devDependencies a shot, so this configuration will not impact production). Once we'll validate, I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 7):

You could avoid modifying your `package.json` file by using the `npm link` command. This will automatically configure the `execution` package to symlink its `node_modules/common` directory to your local clone of `common`.

**How to use this method**

1. Inside your `common` directory type: `npm link`. This will create a global reference to your `common` folder in `npm`, identified by `common` (assuming `common` is the exact name of your node package).
2. Inside your `execution` directory type: `npm link common`. This will symlink the `node_modules/common` folder into your local copy of the `common` directory.

When you're done making changes to your `common` folder, you need to update that package online, and then change the `package.json` of `execution` to point to the updated version of `common`.

I prefer this method over the one suggesting to point `package.json` to your local repository, because that leaves your `package.json` in an invalid state that you might accidentally commit and push.

Answer (score 0):

#### Problems with npm link

`npm link` generally works quite well, but there's a few issues with it when you have a more complex linking of several packages:

1. It's slow.
2. It's difficult to unlink things when you're done testing locally.  You could run `npm unlink` or `npm unlink <package-name>` but that will remove it from `package.json`.  `npm i` also does not remove the link.
3. It doesn't work if you have more than one level of dependencies you want linked, especially when there are complex relationships with the dependencies such as:

```
- root:
-- dependencyC
-- dependencyA [linked]:
--- dependencyB
-- dependencyB [linked]:
--- dependencyC
```

As `dependencyC` will be a different reference within `root` and `dependencyB`.  You'd have to link all such dependencies locally for it to work.  Not so much an issue with functional programming, but for OO classes/prototypes, it will say the reference does not match.

#### Solution

While looking for a solution to this problem with our own development, I came across https://github.com/coopcycle/coopcycle-js/issues/4 which mentions to simply use `ln -sf <link>` instead of `npm link` as `ln` creates a symlink for you.  It's fast (instantaneous), easy to comprehend, and easy to undo (just run `npm i`).

Given the same example above (wanting to link `dependencyA` and `dependencyB` to `root`) you would run:

**In root:**

```
/root % npm i
/root % cd node_modules
/root % rm -rf dependencyA
/root % rm -rf dependencyB
/root % ln -sf ../../../dependencyA
/root % ln -sf ../../../dependencyB
```

*Assuming `../../../dependencyA` is the relative path to `dependencyA`.*

**In dependencyA:**

```
/root % npm i
/root % cd node_modules
/root % rm -rf dependencyB
/root % ln -sf ../../../root/node_modules/dependencyB
```

**In dependencyB:**

```
/root % npm i
/root % cd node_modules
/root % rm -rf dependencyC
/root % ln -sf ../../../root/node_modules/dependencyC
```